# how to get path to images in the uploads folder to be used in a plugin

Tags: plugins, images, themes

I have some folder with images in `/wp-content/uploads`. I also have a plugin file in `/wp-content/plugins`. I want to retrieve the images stored in `/wp-content/uploads` and use them in the plugin file.

I have tried

```
echo'<img src="../../USER_PHOTOS/ronny'" href="#"></img>';
```

can someone show me how I can get the path to these images?
thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If I'm not mistaken, you may want to try the [wp_uploads_dir](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) function, like so:

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir(); 

echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $uploads['baseurl'] . '/USER_PHOTOS/ronny/' ) . '" href="#">';
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is a documented [bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25449) where `wp_upload_dir()` does not honor https (ssl). My suggestion is to write a wrapper to remove the protocol from the returned URL to make it adaptable to the environment:

```
function wp_upload_dir_url() {
  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $upload_dir = $upload_dir['baseurl'];
  return preg_replace('/^https?:/', '', $upload_dir);
};
echo(wp_upload_dir_url() . '/2017/01/my-img.jpg');
// outputs something like '//mysite.test/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/my-img.jpg'
// which is perfectly acceptable as an img src
```

If you are concerned about the performance hit of using `preg_replace()` multiple times, then set a constant in your functions.php file:

```
define('WP_UPLOAD_DIR_URL', wp_upload_dir_url() . '/');
```

Answer (score 2):

[Dan S](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/117833/dan-s) points out a trac ticket where `wp_upload_dir()` does not support https. I've not found this to be the case on my sites, but if it does affect you, then you can add a filter to `upload_dir` and manually return the correct protocol based on the `is_ssl()` conditional.

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', function( $upload_dir ){
  return array_map( function( $value ) {
    return is_ssl() ?
      str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $value ) :
      str_replace( 'https://', 'http://', $value );
  }, $upload_dir );
}, 10, 1 );
```

Then you can continue using `wp_upload_dir()` as you always have.

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446314/why-use-protocol-relative-urls-at-all), unless you have specific performance concerns you should use https://.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I used `wp_upload_dir();` [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to access an image file named "rock_01.jpg" uploaded to the wordpress folder "uploads/complete-theme/"

```
<?php $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/complete-theme/rock_01.jpg'; ?>" />
```

It worked as expected.